# keep variable throughout the life of the application in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, file, variables

I need to keep variable throughout the life of the application. It shouldn't be disposed NEVER.

I was thinking of two methods:

1. Keep it the file
2. Store in database in separate table

But in the second case, create a separate table for one row isn't very clever.
So how to achieve that?

Comment: What type of variable is this?

Comment: Is this part of an application configuration? should this value be mutable?

Comment: A `static` variable maybe?

Comment: Type of variable is integer and it will incrementing when some operation happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on where the property is initialised:

1. It could be stored within the Application Scope -

   There are different scopes with ASP.NET and other scopes are Session and Request

   [ASP.NET Application State Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594.aspx)

   [ASP.NET Session State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)
2. Alternatively set as a static property within the Global.asax
3. Set as a app setting in Web.Config if its immutable

   `<appSettings>
       <add name="fixedProperty" value="fixedValue" />
   </appSettings>`

   and reference anywhere within the application using

   `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fixedProperty"]`

   (although this call to configuration to should moved to a single static Settings file to make call to property reusable with one accessor to the web.config - type can also be converted from string to whatever you may require too)
4. As you already mentioned, persist to file or database - there is nothing wrong with persisting the single record to a database.  That's what the data store is for.

Comment: Variable will changes and i must sure that if server down, it will saved.

Comment: If variable can change and should be restored on server restart then you must persist it - either to a file or database everytime it changes.  

There is nothing wrong with saving a single record to a database.

Save the property every time it is changed to ensure it is available next time server restarts.

Answer (score -1):

You can make that variable as a static variable in a class like StaticData.java and use it with the class name. If you want to access the variable only at client side you can use localstorage.set().

Comment: This variable must be stored at server side and C# code will operating with it.

Comment: You can configure your variable in your configuration files.. I have came across the same situation like this in my current project. I solved this by saving the constant values as static in my SystemParams.java file.

Comment: Thanks, can you give some links about SystemParams.java?
And what if server down?

Comment: The question is regarding server variables but not variables that are stored in the browser localstorage.